# Changing Entry variable on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so I am trying to get the file path from the file directory using tkinter. My current script doesn't raise any errors but it's not doing what I want it to do. So I created an input with text inside and I want to swap that text out for the file path, but also give the option of typing/editing it out before and after the text is changed. This is what I have right now

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import filedialog

class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def browseFiles(self):
        filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                               title = "Select a File",
                                               filetypes = (("Pictures",
                                                             "*.jpg*"),
                                                            ("All files",
                                                             "*.*")))
        self.e3.configure(textvariable=filename1)

    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="Picture path:").grid(row=4)
        Label(master, text="...").grid(row=3, column=2)
        Label(master, text="Picture 2 path:").grid(row=5)

        text = tk.StringVar()
        text.set('Enter or browse picture/path')
        #input fields for tags
        #Entry fields
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)
        self.e3 = Entry(master, textvariable = text, fg = 'red')
        self.e4 = Entry(master)
        self.e5 = Entry(master, textvariable = text, fg = 'red')
        self.e6 = Entry(master)
        self.e7 = Entry(master)
```

I'm guessing there is something going wrong in `def browseFiles(self)`. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: `filename1` is a string, not an instance of the `StringVar` class, so is not a suitable value for `e3`'s `textvariable`. If you want to put the string value _into_ `e3`, use `self.e3.set(filename1)`.

Comment: @martineau `self.e3` is an `Entry` which does not have `set()` function.  OP should change `text` to instance variable `self.text`, then use `self.text.set(filename1)` inside `browseFile()`.

Comment: @acw1668: My mistake — `Entry`s have a `get()` but not a `set()` — so making `text` an instance variable and calling its `set()` method as you've indicated is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed 2 different strategies. Either you use configure to set the text attribute on a Label:

```
class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def browseFiles(self): 
        self.e3.configure(text=filename1)

    def body(self, master):
        self.e3 = Label(master, fg = 'red')
```

Or use the insert command on an Entry:

```
class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def browseFiles(self):
        self.e3.delete('0', tk.END)
        self.e3.insert('0', filename1)

    def body(self, master):
        self.e3 = Entry(master, fg = 'red')
```

Or you make a StringVar() and set that instead (Entry or Label):

```
class Initial(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def browseFiles(self): 
        self.e3_text.set(filename1)

    def body(self, master):
        self.e3_text = tk.StringVar()
        e3 = Entry(master, textvariable=self.e3_text, fg = 'red')
```